# Flutter jank on first open iOS even after shader compilation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am getting this serious jank on my app launch. I have tried shader compilation as suggested in official flutter documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/shader) but it won't disappear.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Google drive video link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BaHoKlI0XhWqiYJHBcRcNBD-VHsamCbF/view

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @SyedRajin Yes I was able to fix it. I wrote a Medium article stating the solution. Link to the article is: https://bilaldrndo.medium.com/how-to-remove-flutter-animation-jank-lagging-ios-and-android-5c59c92ab382

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the flutter channel to **master** it has new rendreing engine `Impeller` embedded for preview results are astonishing.